# TypeError: authorField.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, typeerror

I am so confused. I don't know why its popping the "not a function" error.
Here's the code:

```
  const blankAuthor = { name: "", email: "" };
  const [authorField, setAuthorField] = useState([{ ...blankAuthor }]);

authorField.map((data, index) => {
            console.log(data, index);
}
```

Comment: you cant use map over an object

Comment: i have to add more data to the array.

Comment: Why are using using map here - purpose? Can write more explanation or more of your code to help you.

Comment: i am trying to dynamically add new input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are looking for dynamic inputs . This might help you get started

```js
function App() {
  const [authorFields, setAuthorFields] = React.useState([
                                            {
                                              name: "test1",
                                              email: "email1"
                                            },
                                            {
                                              name: "test2",
                                              email: "email2"
                                            }]);

  const changeValue = index => e => {
     let propertyName = e.target.name;
     let newArr = [...authorFields];
     newArr[index][propertyName] = e.target.value;
     setAuthorFields(newArr);
  };

  return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {authorFields.map((data, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <input
               type="text"
               name="name"
               value={data.name}
               onChange={changeValue(index)}
            />
            <input
               type="text"
               name="email"
               value={data.email}
               onChange={changeValue(index)}
            />
        </li>
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

 ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <App />
  </div>,
  document.querySelector("#app")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```